# NOT IN sub select from T SQL to LINQ?

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

Trying to write a LINQ query here to replicate NOT IN from T SQL. Here's the SQL query I want in LINQ:

```
select * from schema.Table1
where TableId NOT IN (select pa.TableId from schema.Table2 ta
where ta.SecondaryId = myParameter)
```

Had a look at previous posts but haven't quite got it to work.

```
var query = from a in _Context.Table1
                    where a.TableId != _Context.Table2.Any(ta=>(ta.SecondaryId== myParameter))
                    select a;
```

Comment: store Table2.TableId list in variable and then change linq to something like this: `where !idList.Any(x=>x == a.TableId)` or `idList.All(x=>x != a.TableId)`

Comment: I would advise against using LinqToSQL if at all possible due to the issues outlined by @Christos, amongst other huge bugs and missing features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
// get all the values that you want to exclude in a list.
var excluded = (from t in _Context.TableId
                select t.TableId
                where t.SecondaryId == myParameter).ToList();

// get all the items from Table1 that aren't contained in the above list
var query = from t in _Context.Table1
            where excluded.Contains(t.TableId)==false
            select t;
```

or

```
// get all the values that you want to exclude in a list.
var excluded = _Context.TableId
                       .Where(x=>x.SecondaryId == myParameter)
                       .Select(x=>x.TableId)
                       .ToList();

// get all the items from Table1 that aren't contained in the above list
var query = _Context.Table1.Where(a=>!excluded.Any(a.TableId));
```

Comment: @halit aggreed but I am not sure if the OP can avoid this since it uses linq to sql and I am not sure if `Any` can be translated in to  sql.

Comment: Your sample sends 2 query to sql server. IT can be done 1 query by using join or exists. But Your query is exactly true. Just performance issue :)

Comment: Great @Christos, used your first example, produce a list of the excluded records then use .Contains == false in the actual where clause. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var query = from a in _Context.Table1
            where _Context.Table2.Any(ta=>ta.SecondaryId== a.TableId) == false
            select a;
```

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to this...its not pretty...but it might just work given the limited features set of LinqToSQL

```
IQueryable<Table2> excluded = from t in _Context.Table2
                           where t.SecondaryId == myParameter
                           select t;

// get all the items from Table1 that aren't contained in the above list
IQueryable<Table1> query = from t1 in _Context.Table1
                           join t2 in excluded on t1.TableId equals t2.TableId into foo
                           from e in foo.DefaultIfEmpty()
                           where e == null
                           select t;
```

This query should result in the equivalent of

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE SecondaryId == @myParameter) t2 
          ON t1.TableId = t2.TableId
WHERE t2.TableId IS NULL
```